# I seem to need both @OneToOne and @OneToMany relationship

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm writing an app to operate a collection of hardware that is supposed to be setup and shutdown repeatedly in different locations.

I want to track those installations so I've created separate entities for a physical object itself and the installation.

Station object needs to keep track of up to one (null while not installed) active installation information (so @OneToOne) but also all the previous installations (so @OneToMany)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "station")
class Station{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "stationInstallation", cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, 
    CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "station_installation_id", nullable = true)    
    private StationInstallation activeStationInstallation;
    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.Lazy, mappedBy = "station_id", cascade =      
    {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, 
    CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })

    private List<stationInstallation> stationInstallations;
    
    ...
}
```

The other entity will have the station id, location and date of the setup as well as the shutdownDateTime being null.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "stationInstallation")
 class StationInstallation{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy ="stationInstallation", cascade - CascadeType.ALL)
    private Station station;

    @Column(name = "location")
    private String location;

    @Column(name = "setupDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime setupDateTime;

    @Column(name = "shutdownDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime shutdownDateTime

}
```

Finally the shutdown method is supposed to unattach the entity from the Station entity by setting activeStationInstallation to null and setting shutdownDateTime to LocalDateTime.NOW.

```
    ...
    stationInstallation.getStation().setActiveStationInstallation(null);
    stationInstallation.setShotdownDateTime(LocalDateTime.NOW);
    ...
```

But that will obviously result in a growing number of StationInstallation "finished" objects, which would seem to require @ManyToOne relation with the Station all the while I want to keep @OneToOne relation with the activeStationInstallation.

What do?

I figured I could just make another entity calling it FinishedStationInstallation, remove shutdownDateTime from StationInstallation, make both immutable and instead of adding shutdownDateTime with a setter add it in the constructor while deleting the active version. And immutablity is an asset, ut at the same time I'd have to add several new tables to the db and keep track of and query two entities instead of one.

EDIT: I guess I could get rid of List stationInstallations from the 1st entity, since I don't really need to keep the track of it beyond db queries, but I added it for the clarity of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would model it this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "station")
class Station{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, 
    CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "station_installation_id", nullable = true)    
    private StationInstallation activeStationInstallation;
    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.Lazy, mappedBy = "station", cascade =      
    {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, 
    CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })

    private List<stationInstallation> stationInstallations;
    
    ...
}

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "stationInstallation")
 class StationInstallation{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(mappedBy ="stationInstallation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Station station;

    @Column(name = "location")
    private String location;

    @Column(name = "setupDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime setupDateTime;

    @Column(name = "shutdownDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime shutdownDateTime

}
```

- The one-to-one relation from Station to installation has a FK => so no mapped by
- The one-to-many relation from Station to installation is mapped by the `station` association on installation, which obviously has to be a many-to-one association, since the other side is a one-to-many